# Karp hardness of a vector system allocation

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

Given an **undirected** graph $G(V,E)$, a **vector system** is a set $S$ of ordered pair (intuitively called **vector**) $(u,v)$ (we shall call $u$ the **initial point**, and $v$ the **terminal point**) that satisfies the following criteria:

- For each vector $(u,v)\in S$, we have that $uv \in E(G)$. So, each vector must be an orientation of an edge
- No two vectors share the same **initial point**. Formally, for every two vectors $(u,v),(w,x)\in S$, we have that $u\neq w$
- An initial point of a vector cannot be the terminal point of other vector. Formally, for every two vectors $(u,v),(w,x)\in S$, we have that $v\neq w$

Now, our problem is defined as follows:

> **Input**: An undirected graph $G(V, E)$ and a natural number $k$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if it is possible to allocate a vector system of size $k$ in $G$, otherwise **NO**

What is the hardness of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Omitting the second requirement (allowing vectors to share initial points)**:

This becomes $\mathrm{NP}$-complete since it is exactly $\mathrm{MAX}$-$\mathrm{CUT}$.

Consider the set of all terminal points of the vector system. Exclude all the edges between any two vertices of this set. All the edges inwards constitute the cut.

**Putting back the second requirement (vectors required not to share inital points)**

This is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete by a reduction from $\mathrm{DOMINATING\ SET}$.

Reverse the direction of the vector system.

We see that now the set of initial points (originally terminal points) are dominating the set of terminal points (originally initial points). **Note that these two sets are disjoint**.

So, given an instance $(G,k)$ of $\mathrm{DOMINATING\ SET}$. Our reduction just produces $(G,n-k)$ where $n=|V(G)|$ as an instance of the vector allocation system.

If there is a dominating set of size $k$, then for each of the dominated $n-k$ vertices, we can assign for it a dominating vertex among $k$ dominating vertices. The direction is from the dominating vertex to the dominated vertex (this is the reversed direction). We have formed a (reversed) vector system of size $n-k$.

Conversely, if there exists a vector system of size $n-k$. The set of terminal points (originally initial points) are of size exactly $n-k$. Take the remaining $k$ vertices as a dominating set. This shows that the original instance of $\mathrm{DOMINATING\ SET}$ is a **YES** instance.